2021: a year in moderation

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the preceding calendar year.
As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
-- A Theory of Moderation

That doesn't eliminate the need for having moderators altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.
So as we say goodbye to 2021, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some exciting stats. Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Bitcoin over the past 12 months:




Action
Moderators
Community¹




Users suspended²
0
36


Users destroyed³
112
0


Users deleted
1
0


Users contacted
3
0


Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue
125
479


Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue
4
78


Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue
16
423


Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue
1
300


Tasks reviewed⁴: First questions queue
9
403


Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue
24
2,040


Tasks reviewed⁴: First answers queue
2
149


Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue
40
2,090


Tags merged
42
0


Tag synonyms proposed
20
0


Tag synonyms created
20
0


Revisions redacted
2
0


Questions reopened
27
0


Questions protected
1
137


Questions migrated
17
0


Questions merged
3
0


Questions flagged⁵
82
1,477


Questions closed
579
745


Question flags handled⁵
661
898


Posts unlocked
0
1


Posts undeleted
13
46


Posts locked
3
485


Posts deleted⁶
821
1,907


Posts bumped
0
2,706


Escalations to the Community Manager team
1
0


Comments undeleted
18
0


Comments flagged
2
79


Comments deleted⁷
314
592


Comment flags handled
56
25


Answers flagged
145
2,443


Answer flags handled
1,821
768


All comments on a post moved to chat
1
0



Footnotes
¹ "Community" here refers both to the membership of Bitcoin without diamonds next to their names, and to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.
² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.
³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.
⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.
⁵ Includes close flags (but not close or reopen votes).
⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.
⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).
Further reading:

Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: 2020: a year in moderation

You can also check out this report on other sites

Or peruse detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites


Wishing everyone a happy 2022! ^_^
